# How to resolve CORS error in Oracle Cloud

Tags: cloud, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I'm evaluating Oracle Cloud and I was able to run 7 Spring microservices. My frontend is Angular and all of them runs in docker containers managed by Docker-Compose.

The issue I face is when the front-end angular sends request to a backend service, I get a CORS error. What surprises me is both the Angular and microservices are running in the same domain with a public IP.

Attached is the screenshot.

[image]

Please note that all controllers are annotated with `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")`

Answer (score 0):

Is http://140.238.167.40:8083 your service? Above it says "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status". To me, this sounds like the OPTIONS call (to check CORS permissions) sent from the browser to http://140.238.167.40:8083 is not receiving an HTTP 200 back from the service, which is the first step in checking if the CORS permissions are open enough for the XHR request to be allowed.

Please check the service's logs to see how it responded to the OPTIONS request, and/or use the browser's network traffic developer tools to see what response the service returned.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a very application specific error, but I would suggest verifying connectivity to the endpoint in question, as there may be an egress/network connection limitation preventing the connection.  Can you do a CURL to the HTTP address http://140.238.167.40:8083/ and the specific URL?